# how can I provide thread safety to my code?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static long total = 0;
        static long count(int row)
        {
            /* do_something .. every operation is thread safe here */
            return somevalue;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parallel.For(0, 10000000, i => //some big limit to test threading is working
            {
                total += count(i);
                // however, collecting 'somevalue' from 'count()' operation isn't thread safe.
            });

            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to parallelize above code. I have to do one billion operation of `count()` from 0 to 10^9 - 1. the `count()` function itself shares no data with other threads. however, adding up results from `count()` to `total` ain't thread safe - the results differ every time I run the program. `total` has to store some integral value that can't be stored in int. Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: Parallel LINQ, with `Select(i=>count(i)).Sum()` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one-liner using [`Sum(ParallelQuery<Int64>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413244.aspx) to combine the projection and the summation.

```
long total = ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Sum(row => count(row));
```

Answer (score 2):

Parallel LINQ makes this easy:

```
ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Select(i=>count(i)).Sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.increment(v=vs.100).aspx

You could also use the standard lock() too.

Comment: While lock and atomic increment fix the correctness problem, they hurt performance tremendously. If count is a function that little time to execute, the result is probably slower than serial. With slower count you may see some speedup. Adding more threads won't do any good either.